# disable showing thumbnails at the end of video in iframe apii

Tags: youtube-api

I use youtube iframe api for embedding some videos. I observe that at the end of the video, api displays some thumbnails/videos (as recommendations) for next watch.

How can I disable that? I want it to be blank or can I customize? I do something like this:

```
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player1', {
        height: YTPlayerHeight,
        width: YTPlayerWidth,
        playerVars: { 'autoplay': 1, 'showinfo' : 0, controls: 0 },
        videoId: firstVideoId,
        events: {
            'onReady': onReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
        }
    });
}
```

Pleas help

Comment: use 'rel':0 in the playerVars

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting [`rel: 0`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#rel) as one of the `playerVars` will disable the end screen. All of the supported parameters are listed in [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters).

Answer (score 0):

Just setting parameter - **related**: **false**